# How to convert Multiple sheet into PDF landscape

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code I am using. This works fine and converts the first 2 sheets to landscape. But I don't know why it's not converting sheet3 and sheet4 to landscape orientation. Can someone help me on this:-

```
Public Sub SaveSheetsAsPDF()

     Dim wksAllSheets As Variant
     Dim wksSheet1 As Worksheet
     Dim strFilename As String, strFilepath As String

    'Set references up-front
    Set wksSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     wksAllSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")
      For Each sh In wksAllSheets
        Sheets(sh).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    Next
    'strFilepath  = "C:\"

     'Create the full Filename using cells D6, E6 and F6
     With wksSheet1
         'Assemble the string cell-by-cell, "D6 E6-F6"
         strFilename = strFilepath & .Range("D6").Value & " " & _
                                     .Range("E6").Value & "-" & _
                                     .Range("F6").Value & ".pdf"
     End With

     'Save the Array of worksheets (which will be selected) as a PDF
    ' ThisWorkbook.
     Sheets(wksAllSheets).Select
     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
               Type:=xlTypePDF, _
               Filename:=strFilename, _
               Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
               IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
               IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
               OpenAfterPublish:=True

     'Make sure all the worksheets are NOT left selected
     wksSheet1.Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW, your code works for me.

Comment: Is there only one workbook open at the time?  I'm wondering whether `Sheets(sh).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape` (which is equivalent to `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sh).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape`) is perhaps operating on the wrong workbook.  (But you are using `Sheets(wksAllSheets).Select` later, so it **should** be OK.)

Comment: You could debug it by placing a lot of `Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet2").PageSetup.Orientation & "|" & Sheets("Sheet3").PageSetup.Orientation` statements through your code, and see whether it at any time writes out `2|2` (2 being landscape, 1 being portrait) and then changes back to `2|1` - if it did that it would imply that the setting it to landscape was working but something was then changing it back again.

Comment: I tried adding these debug statements throughout my code, I can see its displaying 2|2 everywhere. but when I look at the generated PDF file, The sheet with more columns get break into multiple pdf pages instead of 1. please suggest

Comment: is there any way by which I can shrink the data of each sheet to single page. for example if there are more columns in any of the sheet , it should fit into the same page instead of breaking into multiple pdf pages.

Comment: `.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1` and `.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1` to force the Print Area to fit into one page.

Comment: If your question is not "how do I make it print Landscape instead of Portrait", but is actually "My output is displayed Landscape but takes several pages - how do I make it fit on one page" then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45180917/edit) the question to say that.  Then @PatricK can post his comment as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

please try this. set the *strFilename* variable before you run it.

if it still fails, export each sheet manually, just to pinpoint the failing sheet

```
Public Sub SaveSheetsAsPDF()

    Dim wksAllSheets As Sheets
    Set wksAllSheets = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"))

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In wksAllSheets
        sh.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    Next

    Dim strFilename As String
    strFilename = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Book1.pdf"   ' set up path to test file

    wksAllSheets.Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                    Filename:=strFilename, _
                     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

 End Sub
```